# how to make the newsletter checkbox checked by default in prestashop?

Tags: checkbox, prestashop-1.6, newsletter

I am using Prestashop and I want the newsletter checkbox to be checked by default. For that, I edited the file : `Theme/myTemplate/authentification.tpl`

I Changed the following lines from:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="1" {if isset($smarty.post.newsletter) AND $smarty.post.newsletter == 1} checked="checked"{/if} />
    <label for="newsletter">{l s='Sign up for our newsletter!'}</label>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="1" {if isset($smarty.post.newsletter) AND $smarty.post.newsletter == 1} checked="checked"{/if} checked="checked" />
    <label for="newsletter">{l s='Sign up for our newsletter!'}</label>
</div>
```

but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your approach is right and you could remove the condition which is useless now:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="newsletter">{l s='Sign up for our newsletter!'}</label>
</div>
```

Did you try clearing the cache in `Backoffice` > `Advanced Parameters` > `Performance`? Also on this page is the option `Recompile templates if the files have been updated` checked?

---

Also note that this practice is forbidden in certain country (France for example)

---

For One page checkout you need to do the same changes in `/themes/your_theme/order-opc-new-account.tpl` and `/themes/your_theme/order-opc-new-account-advanced.tpl`.

Comment: Yes i've done all the but it is still not working.
ps: i rmoved the option as you mentioned

Comment: how am i suppose to do it in legal way ?

Comment: You can't check an opt-in without the user consent. The user shall check the checkbox himself. Pre-checked checkbox is not consider a proper optin.

Comment: by the way, it was not working because i was using one page check out. and true it's not good nbut impossible to convince my boss.thanks anyway for the answer. and if you know how to do it with one page checkout it whould be really nice ;)

Comment: For One page checkout you need to do the same changes in `/themes/your_theme/order-opc-new-account.tpl` and `/themes/your_theme/order-opc-new-account-advanced.tpl`.